# Cannot use "floor" in swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
var viewSize = Double(viewersView.frame.size.width)
var itemSize = Double(boxSize + viewerHorizontalPadding)
self.maxViewers = floor(viewSize / itemSize) //should be Int
```

I get an error that says:

> No "floor" candidates produce expected contextual result type "Int"

I imported Darwin.

Comment: Check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51630557/4061501

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`floor` takes a Double and returns another Double. If you want it to be an Int (to match `self.maxViewers`, you must convert it explicitly: `Int(floor(viewSize / itemSize))`.

Comment: Or just `Int(viewSize / itemSize)`.

Comment: @MartinR I'm being pedantic, but that's not quite the same - `Int(..)` will truncate, not round down like `floor` i.e. `floor(-1.1)` would be `2.0`, but `Int(-1.1)` would be `-1`. Also, it's unsafe; you can have larger floats than integers can handle i.e. `let f = Float(Int64.max)+1` is fine, but `let i = Int(f)` now throws an error :| (Though, the answer has that problem as too)

Comment: The documentation should be more precise. I would bet that `Int(..)` *truncates* towards zero. Perhaps someone can look it up in the source code :)

Comment: @deanWombourne: Good points (but probably not relevant in *this* use case).

Comment: And submit a PR improving the comment ;)

Comment: @MartinR You're bet is correct! But we need not re-visit the source code to verify this claim. Somewhat hidden in [The Language Guide - The Basics: Integer and Floating-Point Conversion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html), it is stated that: _"Floating-point values are always truncated when used to initialize a new integer value in this way. This means that `4.75` becomes `4`, and `-3.9` becomes `-3`."_ So same as e.g. integer division in C/C++; simply discarding the fractional part.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`round(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/2298113-round) method or [`rounded(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/2885638-rounded)

> `round(_:)`]: Rounds the value to an integral value using the specified rounding
> rule.
> `rounded(_:)`: Returns this value rounded to an integral value using the specified rounding rule

```
var w1 = 6.5
w1.round()
// w1 == 7.0

// Equivalent to the C 'round' function:
var w = 6.5
w.round(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
// w == 7.0

// Equivalent to the C 'trunc' function:
var x = 6.5
x.round(.towardZero)
// x == 6.0

// Equivalent to the C 'ceil' function:
var y = 6.5
y.round(.up)
// y == 7.0

// Equivalent to the C 'floor' function:
var z = 6.5
z.round(.down)
// z == 6.0
```